# Apache + mod_wsgi - parallel requests from same browser

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, mod-wsgi

could you be so kind and help me with the problem?

I'm running Apache 2.2.22 with mod_wsgi

I configured WSGI properly to work on multiple threads and am using Python
I need to handle parallel requests from same browser, but the only parallel request wsgi can serve are the ones coming from different browsers (or 1 browser tab + 1 tab in incognito).

I tried both embedded and daemon.

Apache configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess appname processes=5 threads=25 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup appname 

WSGIScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    AddHandler wsgi-script .py
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    #Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I put wsgi.py in /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory with 755 mod

the content of wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

def application(environ, start_response):

    sys.stderr.write("before wait time = %s\n" % str(datetime.now()))
    sys.stderr.write("client= %s\n" % environ['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    sys.stderr.write("waiting\n")
    print >> sys.stderr, 'mod_wsgi.process_group = %s' % repr(environ['mod_wsgi.process_group'])
    time.sleep(10)
    sys.stderr.write("wait finished time = %s\n" % str(datetime.now()))
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

When requesting http://my.ip/cgi-bin/wsgi.py I'm getting all fine, but when I run it parallel in 2 tabs of single browser, the second tab is waiting for the first to finish ...
logs:

```
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:06 2014] [error] before wait time = 2014-09-02 18:25:06.365133
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:06 2014] [error] client= 192.168.113.35
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:06 2014] [error] waiting
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:06 2014] [error] mod_wsgi.process_group = 'appname'
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:16 2014] [error] wait finished time = 2014-09-02 18:25:16.371944
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:16 2014] [error] before wait time = 2014-09-02 18:25:16.390348
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:16 2014] [error] client= 192.168.113.35
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:16 2014] [error] waiting
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:16 2014] [error] mod_wsgi.process_group = 'appname'
[Tue Sep 02 18:25:26 2014] [error] wait finished time = 2014-09-02 18:25:26.400464
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not be surprised if this has to do with the browser recycling open connections to the server to send subsequent requests.  If it opens a new connection for a request sent from an incognito tab, that would allow a separate thread on the server to handle it; that this works properly shows that your WSGI setup is basically ok.